# RabbitMQ installation on Amazon Web Services EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq, amazon-eks

Does AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service have the same concept as Google Kubernetes Engine apps via a marketplace? I'm looking to deploy RabbitMQ and previously accomplished this on GKE.

Otherwise, it looks like there's a helm chart or I can manually do this via the container on dockerhub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS does have a marketplace where you can utilize various AMI's or deploy a certified Bitnami RabbitMQ image. You can see that for yourself here: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace

The downside is that this isn't something available for AWS EKS and as a result we will have to install/maintain this ourselves. That could look something like using the stable/rabbitmq-ha chart with anti-affinity across AZ's, quorum queues, and EBS.

Learn more about helm here:
https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/

Learn more about the rabbitmq helm chart here: https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/rabbitmq-ha

Answer (score 1):

No, you need top deploy it by your own.